# Download trello attachment nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, trello

Good Day

Any one have an example, on how to download Card Attachment from trello, using nodejs?

I'f you have any idea please share it with me.

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but find this from simple search:

https://github.com/adunkman/node-trello#fetching-card-data

```
var Trello = require("node-trello");
var t = new Trello("<your key>", "<token>");

t.get("/1/members/me", function(err, data) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log(data);
});

// URL arguments are passed in as an object.
t.get("/1/members/me", { cards: "open" }, function(err, data) {
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have that one.
But this example will fetch all the data on the board/card.

Want to fetch image attachment from the specific card.

Answer (score 0):

This works, using a combination of the node-trello npm library and a simple HTTPS request. Include your own ENV_SECRET and ENV_TOKEN for your Trello API. The GET request will return a list of JSON objects, 1 for each attachment on the card, specify the indexOfAttachment you want to use and the cardId for the card you want to access.

```
var secret = ENV_SECRET;
var token = ENV_TOKEN;

var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var t = require('node-trello');

downloadAttachment = function () {
    t.get('1/cards/' + cardId + '/attachments', (err, attachmentData) => {
        if (!err) {
            var url = attachmentData[indexOfAttachment].url;
            var filename = url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 1];
            console.log(filename);
            var dest = '.downloads/' + filename;
            var download = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
            https.get(url + '?key=' + secret + '&token=' + token, (res) => {
                res.pipe(download);
                download.on('finish', function () {
                    download.close((err) => {
                        if (!err) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                }).on('error', (err) => {
                    fs.unlink(dest);
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```